# Some countries not colored in map() and no gradient fill in r

Tags: r, dictionary, colorbrewer

I am working on creating a map of Latin America (including Spain) which fills in each country according to a number which is the average of certain speech features. The number is on a continuum, so having a gradient color fill (ie higher numbers are darker) would be perfect. Anyway, here's the code I'm doing:

```
loc <- levels(data$country)
cases <- levels(as.factor(data$mean))
frics <- data.frame(loc,cases)
m <- map('worldHires',plot=F, xlim=c(-120,-35),ylim=c(-60,30), fill=T)
stm <- match.map(m, frics$loc)

frics$rank <- rank(as.numeric(frics$cases), ties='min')
pal <- brewer.pal(max(frics$rank),'Reds')
color <- pal[frics$rank]
frics.color <- color[stm]

map(m,col=frics.color,fill=T, lty=0,boundary=F,interior=F) # fill regions
map('worldHires',interior=T,add=T,col='grey30')
```

Also, here are the corresponding vectors for frics$loc and frics$cases:

```
structure(list(loc = structure(c(7L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 
4L, 3L, 13L, 11L, 2L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Argentina", "Bolivia", 
"Chile", "Colombia", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "El Salvador", 
"Guatemala", "Honduras", "Mexico", "Nicaragua", "Paraguay", "Puerto Rico", 
"Spain"), class = "factor"), cases = c(765, 1582, 928, 1055, 
608, 1780, 1976, 802, 1795, 530, 644, 1160, 633, 930)), .Names = c("loc", 
"cases"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, when I plot the map, it turns out that some countries are not being filled. Most notably, Ecuador, but other Central American Countries as well. I suspect it may be because the color palette I am using does not support 14 different colors. Or maybe something else.

Comment: You're giving one possible cause yourself. I believe you're right. So have you checked whether it actually is the length of the color palette that causes your error?

Comment: The Reds ColorBrewer palette supports a maximum of 9 colors.  Do you get a warning when you run the statement: `pal <- brewer.pal(max(frics$rank),'Reds')`??

Comment: Thanks for the comments. ColorBrewer cannot support more than 12 colors at a time, so I had to ask about finding a new color system. I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it seems that RColorBrewer does not support more than 12 sequential colors in any of their palettes that I could find. I was recommended instead to use the default function in R colorRampPalette(). To solve my problem, I replaced:

```
pal <- brewer.pal(max(frics$rank),'Reds')
color <- pal[frics$rank]
```

With:

```
wbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('white','black')) #spectrum ranges from white to black
color <- wbPal(14) #number of distinct colors
```

The resulting color vector can be as long as you specify, and the colors are gradient steps along the spectrum defined in the first line. In this case, "white -> black". Once I got a color vector that had 14 steps, the other countries filled in appropriately. map()'s "col=" argument will default to NA as a color once the maximum number of colors in the palette has been reached.

Thanks for the feedback.